# location.href is adding a / before pathparam?

Tags: javascript, html, path-parameter

I am trying to use location.href to a folder where a index.php file is located!

So when I am use `location.href = "databases?page=settings";` it redirects me to

**/databases/?page=settings**. Why is Javascript adding a / before the pathparameter?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Use `location.href = "databases/index.php?page=settings";` if that's where you want to navigate. Otherwise, the browser treats `databases` as the folder that it is and appends the `/`.

Comment: Now the / is gone. However, I don't like to see the ```index.php```.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way `href` works, It is designed to change URL to a child page of current page, unless you specify you want to go to another domain (for example having `http://` at the start of the url). If you looking to change URL otherwise, you can use `location.replace(document.location + "databases?page=settings")`

Comment: "It is designed to change URL to a child page of current page" So why does `location.href = "https://google.com/";` take me to https://google.com/ and not to a child page? Perhaps you should amend your statement...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That's because you have specified `https://` at the start of the the string, so it's obvious that you are going to another domain, but for example, `location.href = "google.com/"`; will forward you to `<current_page>/google.com`

Comment: I thing its an Webserver Issue. I am using nginx. My main problem is the trailing slash before the pathParam.